# How to make a condition based on the number of decimals a number has with the IFS and AND functions in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do the following in Google Sheets:

If the number in cell A1 has 4 decimals (for example "1.0001"), and if cell A1>B1 (for example A1=1.0001 and B1=0.0001), and if the string in cell C1 = "Good", then return (A1-B1)*10000.

Additionally:

If the number in cell A2 has 2 decimals (for example "1.01"), and if cell A2>B2 (for example A2=1.01 and B2=0.01), and if the string in cell C2 = "Great", then return (A2-B2)*100.

So far, I've come up with this IFS function:

```
=IFS((AND(A1>B1, C1="Good")), (A1-B1)*10000,(AND(A2>B2, C2="Great")),(A2-B2)*100,TRUE,"ERROR")
```

Which treats the two arguments A1>B1, C1="Good" / A2>B2, C2="Great", within the AND formula.

How can I add the decimal argument to the AND statement?

I thought of setting for something like :

```
=IFS((AND(A1>B1, C1="Good", **A1=(a number with 4 decimals)))**, (A1-B1)*10000,(AND(A2>B2, C2="Great", **A2=(a number with 2 decimals)))**,(A2-B2)*100,TRUE,"ERROR")
```

Where the statements:

A1=(a number with 4 decimals)

and

A1=(a number with 2 decimals)

would do the trick.

How do you formulate those missing "decimal statements"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you mean exactly 4 decimal places, like 1.0001, or at least 4 decimals, which would include 1.000123.

You can test for decimals by using round (or roundup or rounddown) so in the first case:

```
=ifs(and(round(A1,3)<>A1,A1>B1,C1="Good"),(A1-B1)*10000,and(round(A2,1)<>A2,A2>B2,C2="Great"),(A2-B2)*100)
```

But if you wanted it to be exactly 4 decimals:

```
=ifs(and(round(A1,3)<>A1,round(A1,4)=A1,A1>B1,C1="Good"),(A1-B1)*10000,and(round(A2,1)<>A2,round(A2,2)=A2,A2>B2,C2="Great"),(A2-B2)*100)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for that one, It works! I overlooked the 1st point you mentioned, thanks for that too. I was considering the 2nd one and it answers it well. Be well!

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this with one blow:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "\.(.*)")))=4) * 
    (A1:A>B1:B) * (C1:C="Good"),     (A1:A-B1:B)*10000,
 IF((LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "\.(.*)")))=2) * 
    (A1:A>B1:B) * (C1:C="Great"),    (A1:A-B1:B)*100, )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi @player0, thanks a lot for your solution. It works well! You rock! Intreresting the "\.(.*)" formulation. I'll need to study it and get familiar with the reasoning. Thanks a lot for the thoughts shared and food for thought. Take care!

Comment: It works with whole numbers (number without decimals) too, but one has to add the ".00" decimals format for the formula to return the results. How to formate cells with the condition to automatically format any whole number cell (for example 12) to 12.00?

Comment: you mean the import to be formatted before processing or output to be formatted as the final result?

Comment: Yes, the import before proccessing. So that I have your arrayformula already preset and when I enter a whole number in the input cell it automatically change that whole number to a "0.00" format. So that ultimately the result in the arrayformula cell prints.

Comment: I thought of some formula like this: =IF(A1=(a whole number/number without decimals),A1.00(A1 formated as a whole number with two decimals),A1(A1 with any number of decimals>2 decimals)

Comment: You Rock! It works. I will study why and how. Do you mind if I post it as a new question - so you can post your solution with pic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288852/how-to-auto-convert-a-whole-number-into-its-2-decimals-points-equivalent-in-goo