# How to auto-convert a whole number into it's 2 decimals points?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

Following the previous answers
[How to make a condition based on the number of decimals a number has with the IFS and AND functions in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56232416/how-to-make-a-condition-based-on-the-number-of-decimals-a-number-has-with-the-if/56234998?noredirect=1#comment99189609_56234998)

The formula given didn't return a result for whole numbers (any number without decimals, for example: 1(.00), 12(.00) etc.).

To make it return a result also for inputs with whole numbers, 
I thought of some formula like this:

```
=IF(A1=(a whole number/number without decimals),A1.00(A1 formatted as a whole number with two decimals),A1(A1 with any number of decimals>2 decimals).
```

How to make this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "\.(.*)")))=4) * 
    (A1:A>B1:B) * (C1:C="Good"),     (A1:A-B1:B)*10000,
 IF((LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "\.(.*)")))=2) * 
    (A1:A>B1:B) * (C1:C="Great"),    (A1:A-B1:B)*100, )))
```

valid for whole numbers as well?

So that it returns a result for the whole number as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "\.(.*)")))=4) * 
    (A1:A>B1:B) * (C1:C="Good"),     (A1:A-B1:B)*10000,
 IF((LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(TEXT(A1:A, "00.00")), "\.(.*)")))=2) * 
    (A1:A>B1:B) * (C1:C="Great"),    (A1:A-B1:B)*100, )))
```

[image: 0]